# Is there a safe way to run eval in a webpage and avoid it to access the content of the rest of the page?

Tags: javascript, security, eval

I wonder if it is possible to run code provided by users in a webpage in a safe way.

I would like to add code that users can dynamically change to change some of the page behaviour, but I don´t want them to use exploits.

For example, I would like to let the users write a method returning a boolean in a safe way so they do not inject malicious code in the page and alter the dom nor steal info of the rest of the components in the page.

```
function( valuesToUse ) {

  //userprovided logic returning true or false depending on the input
  return valuesToUse.favouriteAnimal === "Lizard"
}
```

Comment: Generally: *no*. If you provide the entire power of the Javascript language and environment to the user, it is somewhere between very hard and impossible to rein that back in. You should create your own mini DSL with custom evaluator which lets users execute only specific, limited expressions, not arbitrary Javascript.

Comment: And how can I do it?

Comment: Look for some "Javascript expression evaluator" library, or something along those lines. Creating a parser from scratch is of course an option, and depending on how complicated expressions you want to allow isn't even all that complicated; but it can quickly get complicated the more freeform code you want to allow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as users only run their own code, there's no need for any security measures. If they break the site, they break it only for themselves.

If these codes are going to be shared, the only reliable way is to have an sandboxed IFRAME and run everything in there (look at how SO snippets, JS fiddle and similar sites work). In this case, user scripts won't be able to interact with the main page though. Here's a good article on the topic: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

If you need userscripts that 1) can interact with the main page AND 2) can be shared between users, then you have to invent your own programming language and compile it to javascript on the fly. There's no option in JS to sandbox the built-in `eval`.

Comment: Note that under many circumstances, self-XSS is also a significant vulnerability. The risk might be lower, but it very much can be an issue. For the most straightforward example, look at the javascript console on Facebook, they even thought of the console as a potential attack vector. While that usually is not treated as such, users copypasting things is very common, and can really be exploited sometimes.

Comment: Also there are several ways for javascript in a frame to interact with the main page, including the `window` object (especially `window.title`), or `postMessage` for example. So running javascript even in a frame is not really secure by itself. The `sandbox` attribute to an iframe helps somewhat.

Comment: @GaborLengyel: thanks, I added an explaining link to the post.

Comment: This link is pretty interesting, it is not exactly what I was looking for but it is a way to solve the issue. I will add this as the response of the question. If someone else is able to give a good approach, please do it, I know some platforms that allow users to add external web components and use some way of isolation between them to enforce privacy, but I don´t know how they do it.